# How to tell composer to use a branch of my fork?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, dependency-management

In a symfony2 project, I am using "jms/serializer-bundle" and I have an issue with one of its dependencies, namely the  `jms/metadata` libary. I have forked the metadata library and included a fix in the `bugfix-doctrine-proxy` branch.

Now I am wondering how to tell composer, that it should use my branch when requiring the dependency?

The composer.json of the serializer library:

```
{
    "name": "jms/serializer",
    "type": "library",
    ...
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "jms/metadata": "~1.1",
        "jms/parser-lib": "1.*",
        "phpcollection/phpcollection": "~0.1",
        "doctrine/annotations": "1.*"
    },
    ...
}
```

My symfony2-project composer.json:

```
{
    ...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@github.com:hauptsacheNet/metadata.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "dev-master",
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about clearly documented, as demostrated by own answer

Comment: @NDM I disagree. If it was as clearly documented, I would not have bothered to ask it at all. And when I hit the same problem again, I will use this question for reference.

Comment: well it turned out to be useful to me :) especially for the "as" alias that is not mentioned in the docs if not with some digging https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was to use a branch alias:

```
{
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@github.com:hauptsacheNet/metadata.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "jms/metadata": "dev-bugfix-doctrine-proxy-class as 1.1",
    },
}
```